# Passing variables to args field in a yaml file, kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am writing a YAML file to use Kubernetes and I wondering how to pass variables to args field.

I need to do something like this :

```
args:  ['--arg1=http://12.12.12.12:8080','--arg2=11.11.11.11']
```

But I don't want to hard code those values for `--arg1` and `--arg2`, instead it should be like,

```
args:  ['--arg1='$HOST1,'--arg2='$HOST2]
```

How should I do this?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/791715/using-environment-variables-in-kubernetes-deployment-spec Followed the accepted answer here, it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options that are quite different and really depend on your use-case, but both are worth knowing:

1) [Helm](https://github.com/helm/helm) would allow you to create *templates* of Kubernetes definitions, that can use variables.
Variables are supplied when you install the Helm chart, and before the resulting manifests are deployed to Kubernetes.
You can change the variables later on, but what it does is regenerate the YAML and re-deploy "static" versions of the result (template+variables=YAML that's sent to Kubernetes)

2) [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) allow you to separate a configuration from the pod manifest, and share this configuration across several pods/deployments.
You can later reference the ConfigMap from your pod/deployment manifests.

Hope this helps!